# JUnit assert, value is between two integers

Tags: java, random, junit

I need to write a JUnit test for an algorithm I wrote that outputs a random integer between two known values.

I need a JUnit test (I.e. an assertEquals like test) that asserts that the out-putted value is between these two integers (or not).

I.e. I have the values 5 and 10, the output would be a random value between 5 and 10. If the test is positive the number was between the two values, otherwise it was not.

Comment: And you can't come up with a logic statement to check for a value being between two numbers?

Comment: mmm... `assertTrue` with the condition being `(i >= 5) && (i <= 10)`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could do an `assertNotEquals` for all the values that are not between 5 and 10.... :-D

Comment: Alternatively, you could write your own matcher and use assertThat

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
@Test
public void randomTest(){
  int random = randomFunction();
  int high = 10;
  int low = 5;
  assertTrue("Error, random is too high", high >= random);
  assertTrue("Error, random is too low",  low  <= random);
  //System.out.println("Test passed: " + random + " is within " + high + " and + low);
}
```

Comment: Heh, I feel like a moron! I very rarely use JUnit and I just couldn't think up how to do it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 21):

you can use junit `assertThat` method (since `JUnit 4.4` )

see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Hamcrest/article.html

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.lessThan;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

......

```
@Test
public void randomTest(){
    int random = 8;
    int high = 10;
    int low = 5;
    assertThat(random, allOf(greaterThan(low), lessThan(high)));
}
```

Comment: This is a superior solution since it gives more useful feedback than `assertTrue` when a test fails.

Answer (score 0):

You may also get an case like one parameter is object other is primitive , which also don't work , just change the primitive into object and you are all set.

For example:

```
Request.setSomething(2);// which is integer field
Integer num = Request.getSomething();

//while testing give the object i.e num 
assertEquals(Request.getSomething(),num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may employ `double` version of `assertEquals`, which supports `delta` parameter:

```
assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)
```

Example:

```
int random = 8;
int high = 10;
int low = 5;

assertEquals((high + low) / 2.0, random, (high - low) / 2.0);
```